# using css file with tiles

Tags: css, struts2, tiles

I m using a css file with tiles but it is not working.

my tiles.xml is:

```xml
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/jsps/mail/mailbase.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="css" value="/css/mail.css" type="string" /> 
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/jsps/mail/menu.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="inbox.tile" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="css" value="/css/mail.css" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsps/mail/inbox.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="msgdetail.tile" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsps/mail/msgDetails.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="compose.tile" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsps/mail/compose.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="msgsent.tile" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsps/mail/msg_sent.html"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

and my jsp is:

```
  <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
    <head>
**<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="<tiles:getAsString name='css'/>"/>**
    </head>
   <body>
<div id="left"><tiles:insertAttribute  name="menu"/></div>
<div id="right"><tiles:insertAttribute  name="body"/></div> 
   </body>
 </html>
```

My CSS file "mail.css" lies in **tomcat_root/web-app-name/css/mail.css**

and jsp is in  **tomcat_root/web-app-name/jsps/mailbase.jsp**

control flow is like:

request---------->inboxaction(struts2.xml)------------------>inbox.tile (tiles.xml)

Comment: What exactly is not working? WHat does the HTML output look like?

Comment: @Pekka: The html output is not showing any of the formatting i described in css file. output is like as if i have not provided css file at all.

Comment: @brightness I mean nwhat does the HTML *code* look like?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="<tiles:getAsString name='css'/>"/>
```

will be translated to

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="/css/mail.css"/>
```

But your CSS file is at `/web-app-name/css/mail.css`.

You should always use `<c:url>` to generate URLs:

```
<tiles:useAttribute id="relativeCssUrl" name="css"/>
<c:url var="absoluteCssUrl" value="${relativeCssUrl}"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="${absoluteCssUrl}"/>
```

Or you might also use

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="${request.contextPath}/<tiles:getAsString name='css'/>"/>
```

Comment: I m trying your solution but can u please tell me that what change i should implement in my method to make it correct. i have seen at several places that this method is also working perfectly.it is not showing any css formatting so there is  surely a path problem.

Comment: Have you read my answer? Just use `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="${request.contextPath}/<tiles:getAsString name='css'/>"/>` to fix your path problem.

Comment: What is the tag definition for "c:" ?

Comment: I see. This is inside of your JSP file. c is the prefix you given to the struts tag library.

Comment: No. c:url is a tag from the JSP standard tag library (aka JSTL). Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info